# Checking for Missingness mechanism

Tags: r, simulation, missing-data

This code is for simulating missing mechanism **randomly** that I extracted it from `imputeR` package :

```
function (data, p = 0.1) 
{
    vec <- c(unlist(data))
    missing <- rbinom(length(vec), 1, p)
    vec[missing == 1] <- NA
    dim(vec) <- dim(data)
    return(vec)
}
```

**But can some one tell me is it missing completely at random (MCAR) or  missing at random (MAR) ?**

Comment: Does $p$ depend on anything when this function is called? Or will it be the same for any record, no matter what other data there is?

Comment: @Björn , I don't think ,p is probability if you increase p number of 1 will be increase it just ratio of missingness .

Comment: That looks MCAR to me since the missingness mechanism doesn't depend on any of the data (either observed or missing), but is instead random. MAR occurs when the missingness mechanism depends upon the observed values (but not the unobserved).

Comment: @hodgenovice , I agree with you . can you help me to change it to MAR . or do you Know how to simulate MAR ?

Comment: @user5934339 if you want to have a function like the one above where you can create MAR missing data from some generic data set, I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

As denoted by Rubin in his original work, MAR (despite of its horrible choice of name) is equivalent to:

$ P(Y\ missing| X, Y) = P(Y\ missing | X) $

Then, since your code is just picking only the size of the dataset for generate a random sample from binomial, and not
data values to conditionally choose the indexes to be set 1, this is MCAR.

To be MAR, you should build some sort of relationship between values of the observed data, and make them give you the missing args in the target vector. You could you use a regression model and a sigmoid or logistic transform to get probabilites to choose where the 1's and 0's will go.

This thing is a little annoying, thanks to the conditions on the observed data.

Another good answer that shows how to implement MAR in one case is:
[Simulate MAR (Missing at Random) data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274374/simulate-mar-missing-at-random-data?rq=1)